# IF Exists in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use IF exists using snowflake but it gives me error.

```
IF(EXISTS(
SELECT DISTINCT 1 as Data_Exist FROM tablename
WHERE NOT TCB_FISCAL_QTR = 'FY'||
  CASE 
   WHEN MONTH( GETDATE()) IN (4,5,6) THEN CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,2), ' Q1')
   WHEN MONTH( GETDATE()) IN (7,8,9) THEN CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,2),' Q2')
   WHEN MONTH( GETDATE()) IN (10,11,12) THEN CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,2),' Q3')
   ELSE CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2),' Q4')
END)
BEGIN 
    SELECT 1 AS abc
END
END IF;
```

I just want syntax in snowflake for If exists dont go with Tablename error.

Comment: So what’s the error?

Comment: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'IF'.

Answer (score 0):

Procedural code needs a stored procedure (unlike TSQL) so you need something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_data_exists()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    data_exists BOOLEAN;

    data_exists = EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM tablename
        WHERE NOT TCB_FISCAL_QTR = 'FY'||
        CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) IN (4,5,6) THEN RIGHT((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+1)::STRING,2) || ' Q1'
            WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) IN (7,8,9) THEN RIGHT((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+1)::STRING,2) || ' Q2'
            WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) IN (10,11,12) THEN RIGHT((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+1)::STRING,2) || ' Q3'
            ELSE RIGHT((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))::STRING,2) || ' Q4'
        END
    );

    IF (data_exists) THEN
        RETURN '1';
    ELSE
        RETURN '0';
    END IF;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

An [IF statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/if) is only valid within a [scripting block](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/blocks), so you'd need a BEGIN/END round your IF statement.